# Type definition should be dependent on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

Given a template class `A`, I want to define a type `T_res` depending on `A`'s template parameters `T_lhs` and `T_rhs`:

```
template< typename T_lhs, typename T_rhs >
class A
{
  // definition of T_res in case "T_lhs and T_rhs are both not primitive types"
  template< bool lhs_is_fundamental = std::is_fundamental<T_lhs>::value,
            bool rhs_is_fundamental = std::is_fundamental<T_rhs>::value,
            std::enable_if_t<( !lhs_is_fundamental && !rhs_is_fundamental )>* = nullptr >
  using T_res = decltype( std::declval<T_lhs>().cast_to_primitive() / std::declval<T_rhs>().cast_to_primitive() );

  // definition of T_res in case "T_lhs and/or T_rhs is a primitive type"
  template< bool lhs_is_fundamental = std::is_fundamental<T_lhs>::value,
            bool rhs_is_fundamental = std::is_fundamental<T_rhs>::value,
            std::enable_if_t<( lhs_is_fundamental || rhs_is_fundamental )>* = nullptr >
  using T_res = decltype( std::declval<T_lhs>() / std::declval<T_rhs>() );

  // ...
};
```

In the first case, where `T_lhs` and `T_rhs` are both not primitiv types, my code is so designed that they represent classes which implement a function `cast_to_primitive()`that returns a primitive type; in this first case, I want `T_res` to have the type that is obtained by dividing an element of type `decltype( std::declval<T_lhs>().cast_to_primitive() )` by an element of the type `decltype( std::declval<T_rhs>().cast_to_primitive() )`.

In the second, where either `T_lhs` or `T_rhs` is a primitive type (or even both) , I want `T_res` to have the type that is obtained by dividing an element of type `T_lhs` by an element of the type `T_rhs`. For example, in case that `T_lhs` is a primitive type, my code is so designed that `T_rhs` can be implicitly casted to an element of type `T_lhs`; the same applies in case that `T_rhs` is primitive.

Unfortunately, the code above does not compile. Error:

```
error: template non-type parameter has a different type 'std::enable_if_t<(lhs_is_fundamental || rhs_is_fundamental)> *' (aka 'typename enable_if<(lhs_is_fundamental || rhs_is_fundamental), void>::type *') in template redeclaration
            std::enable_if_t<( lhs_is_fundamental || rhs_is_fundamental )>* = nullptr >
                                                                            ^
note: previous non-type template parameter with type 'std::enable_if_t<(!lhs_is_fundamental && !rhs_is_fundamental)> *' (aka 'typename enable_if<(!lhs_is_fundamental && !rhs_is_fundamental), void>::type *') is here
            std::enable_if_t<( !lhs_is_fundamental && !rhs_is_fundamental )>* = nullptr >
                                                                              ^
```

Can someone help me to fix the problem?

Comment: `std::conditional_t<..>` might help.

Comment: It would help to know what the purpose of your class `A` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is roughly the same problem found in [Using `std::conditional_t` to define a class' `typedef` in dependence of its template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529543/701092)

The solution is to use `std::conditional` along with helper classes to delay instantiation of the division/call to `cast_to_primitive` until after `std::conditional` is instantiated:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T1, class T2>
struct A
{
  template<class T=T1, class U=T2>
  struct cast_to_primitive_t {using type=decltype(std::declval<T>().cast_to_primitive() / std::declval<U>().cast_to_primitive());};
  template<class T=T1, class U=T2>
  struct primitive_div_t {using type=decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<U>());};

  using T_res = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental<T1>{} && std::is_fundamental<T2>{}, primitive_div_t<>, cast_to_primitive_t<>>::type;
};
```