# Using `std::conditional_t` to define a class' `typedef` in dependence of its template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I try to use `std::conditional_t` to define a class `A`'s `typedef` in dependence of its template parameter `T`:

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
  public:
    typedef std::conditional_t< std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())> type;
};

template< typename T >
class B
{
  public:
    T foo()
    {
      // ...
    }
};


int main()
{
  typename A< int >::type a = 5;    // causes an error
  typename A< B<int> >::type b = 5; // does not cause an error

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code does not compile. Error:

```
error: member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union
        typedef std::conditional_t< std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())> type;
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both types in the conditional expression must be valid, this isn't a SFINAE context.

You can achieve what you want by "executing" only the chosen class template:

```
typedef typename std::conditional_t< std::is_fundamental<T>::value, identity<T>, foo_t<T>>::type type;
```

with those defined as:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity{ using type = T; };

template<typename T>
struct foo_t{ using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()); };
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ESMyjVKTbh2dIPDt)

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me to understand why my code does not cause an SFINAE error?  I see know that an error occurs due to the substitution of `T` by `int`, but I would have expect that the `typedef` is discarded due to an SFINAE and then a corresponding error of the compiler because of the missing typedef.

Comment: @abraham_hilbert it has to do with delaying instantiation of code that would be ill-formed for certain types. Although this is a pretty old version of the documentation, I think it's still a pretty good write-up: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/mpl/doc/paper/mpl_paper.html#delayedeval

Answer (score 2):

The compiler need to instantiate the whole thing when you ask for `::type`. With ints, it's like asking the compiler to give you that type:

```
std::conditional_t<true, int, decltype(std::declval<int>().foo())>
```

But unfortunately, this is ill formed. You'll need to ask the compiler to do some sfinae to choose the right type:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct A {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>> {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
};
```

The compiler will choose the second specialization if possible. In other words, if the type `T` really has `.foo()` possible, then `type` will be equal to the type of that expression.

You can implement `void_t` like that:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

The advantage of this silution is that it don't work only with fundamentals, but the compiler will choose the first version if it can't find a `.foo()` function in the type. You could even add a third version:

```
template<typename T>
struct A<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().bar())>> {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar());
};
```

Now your struct works with types that have `.bar()` too.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct wrap_z{
  template<class...Ts>
  using result=Z<Ts...>;
};

template<bool b, template<class...>class T, template<class...>class F, class...Ts>
using conditional_apply =
  std::conditional_t<
    b, wrap_z<T>, wrap_z<F>
  >::template result<Ts...>;

template<class T>using identity = T;
```

now we use it:

```
public:
  template<class T>using do_foo = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
  using type = conditional_apply< std::is_fundamental<T>{}, identity, do_foo, T>;
```

which I think is clearer at point-of-use than alternatives.