# How to avoid redefinition of typedefs in template class?

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm trying to make a class that gets and sets depending on whether it's passed getters and setters, or just a pointer to a variable to get and set. The idea is that when it's constructed with the pointer argument the TGetter and TSetter members just default to chars and don't do anything. If it's called with the setter and getter constructor then the pointer to the variable defaults to a char and doesn't do anything. I tried to use the std::enable_if with typedefs to decide what the T is, but I get multiple definitions:

```
template <typename TGetter = char, typename TSetter = char, typename Tptr = char> 
struct GetterSetter  
    // IF THE PTR CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED THEN I WANT T TO BE THE TYPE OF TGetter() called result.
    // IF THE GETTER AND SETTER CONSTRUCTOR IS CALLED I WANT T TO BE THE TYPE OF
    // T DEREFERENCED
{
    typedef std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<Tptr, char>, std::invoke_result_t<TGetter>> T;
    typedef std::enable_if < std::is_same_v<TGetter, char>, std::remove_pointer_t<Tptr>> T;
    

    GetterSetter(TGetter getter, TSetter setter) : getter(getter), setter(setter) {}
    GetterSetter(Tptr ptr) : ptrToT(ptr) {}

    TGetter getter;
    TSetter setter;
    Tptr ptrToT;

    T get()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tptr, char>) return *ptrToT;
        else return getter();
    }

    void set(T t)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Tptr, char>) *ptrToT = t;
        else setter(t);
    }
};
```

How to prevent this? I haven't instantiated the class at all, and I'm getting the redefinition compiler error.

Comment: `std::enable_if`-base use SFINAE together with function overload resolution. There's no such thing as overload resolution for typedefs. Only for functions and classes.

Comment: You cannot select a class member depending on how you construct an *object* of that class. T is a member of the class. It exists independently from any objects.

Comment: The way I've seen this written up, the code always used getters and setters, but it had constructors that took pointers of the appropriate type and created appropriate lambdas to use as its getters and setters. That seems a little cleaner than trying to mess around with varying `typedef`s.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson Yes, I think that may be cleaner in the class, but what about whenever you call it, the difference between GetterSetter(&myvariable); and GetterSetter( [ ] {return myvariable;}, [] (int i) { myvariable = i;});

Comment: You can parametrize the class over just `T`, and then instead of `TGetter getter;` you'd have like `std::function<T(void)> getter;`. You write a ctor that takes a `T*` and generates the appropriate lambdas, and then a ctor overload that takes getter and setter functions directly. Calling code would still just look like `getterSetter.get()` and `getterSetter.set(newValue)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `std::enable_if` to select `typedef`s conditionally. To do that you can write:

```
typedef std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<TGetter, char>,
                           std::remove_pointer_t<Tptr>, 
                           std::invoke_result_t<TGetter>> T;
```

or preferably:

```
using T = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<TGetter, char>,
                             std::remove_pointer_t<Tptr>, 
                             std::invoke_result_t<TGetter>>;
```

assuming that `T` must be one of the 2 types.

Comment: Oh, I see. If the case were three or more, would you need to nest them? That gets really confusing to read.

Comment: Hmm, possibly. That could depend on the actual conditions. Edit your question to require a 3way choice, and I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: @Zebrafish A template alias with specializations could be another option for when you need three or more.

Comment: Need to handle when `TGetter` is `char` better (currently tries to evaluate `std::invoke_result_t<char>`). In this case `typename std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<TGetter, char>, std::remove_pointer<Tptr>, std::invoke_result<TGetter>>::type` would work.

Comment: @Artyer I don't think that should be evaluated. Compiles fine at least.

Comment: @super alias templates can't be specialized.

Comment: @cigien Oh, right. Was thinking of template variables.

Comment: @cigien It doesn't compile for me: https://godbolt.org/z/1KEc4P

Comment: @Artyer Oh, I see, but `std::invoke_result<TGetter>>::type` doesn't work either. Looks like another level of indirection is needed.

Comment: Oh yeah, it doesn't compile for me either

Comment: @cigien It works perfectly fine: https://godbolt.org/z/7oM7nz it's a similar case to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529652/5754656

Comment: @Artyer If the pointer's been removed from the int* why does the last line in main() fail? https://godbolt.org/z/8hv8x1

Comment: @Zebrafish Because it's not wrapped in an `if constexpr`. My solution has a bug, but it's not clear if this is the right solution for you. There are other issues with the members of the class. Why are you trying to do this in one class? It seems simpler to have specializations or even 2 classes.

Comment: It's a compiler bug? I tried wrapping it in a constexpr to execute only if the last argument of <TGetter, TSetter, Tptr> isn't char. This should mean that according to the std::conditional the typename T typedef is the int pointer dereferenced, and get() should be assignable to int, right?

Comment: @Zebrafish You would need to use `::type::type` if you use `std::conditional` (no `_t`). My solution had `std::conditional_t<...>::type`

Comment: @Artyer Sorry, I completely lost it. The first type ::type would return the typedef from std::conditional, which is the outermost brackets, I don't know what the second ::type is.  Also, shouldn't the second and third arguments in std::conditional be std::remove_pointer_t<Tptr> and std::invoke_result_t<TGetter> ? With the _t version is supposed to be return you the typedef member inside the struct, right? Without the _t they're the struct itself, not the typedef inside it.